# Mixlib::ShellOut - Windows Impersonation fails

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

I have a TeamCity project that builds binary, uploads a cookbook to Chef Server and converges the node remotely using Windows PowerShell session.

```bsh
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $nd -Credential $cred
$result = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { 
    Cd c:\chef
    chef-client --once -L client.%build.number%.log
    return $LastExitCode
} 
Remove-PSSession $s
```

Everything works fine till ...
I need to execute some binary under different credentials:

```rb
shell = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(cmd, :user => username,
    :domain => domain, :password => password)
shell.run_command
shell.error!
```

Then I receive following error:

```
[2015-08-06T14:17:13+02:00] DEBUG: Re-raising exception: Errno::NOERROR - idm_is3cli[configure_clients_and_scopes] (idm::is3cli line 30) had an error: Errno::NOERROR: No error - CreateProcessAsUserW (You must hold the 'Replace a process level token' permission)
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.1.0-universal-mingw32/lib/mixlib/shellout/windows/core_ext.rb:310:in `create'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.1.0-universal-mingw32/lib/mixlib/shellout/windows.rb:86:in `run_command'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.1.0-universal-mingw32/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:259:in `run_command'
    c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/idm/providers/is3cli.rb:23:in `block in class_from_file'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/lwrp_base.rb:160:in `instance_eval'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/lwrp_base.rb:160:in `block in action'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider.rb:144:in `run_action'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource.rb:586:in `run_action'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:83:in `block in execute_each_resource'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:81:in `execute_each_resource'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:654:in `block in converge'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:649:in `catch'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:649:in `converge'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:688:in `converge_and_save'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:269:in `run'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:252:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:229:in `block in run_chef_client'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:39:in `with_server_connectivity'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:212:in `run_chef_client'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:375:in `run_application'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:60:in `run'
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:65:in `load'
    C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:65:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like you have to update Group Policy on that machine to give that account the ability to replace a process level token:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc957225.aspx)

> `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment`
>
> ## Description
>
> Determines which user accounts can initiate a process to replace the default token associated with a launched subprocess.
>   This user right is defined in the Default Domain Controller Group Policy object (GPO) and in the local security policy of workstations and servers.
>
> By default, only LocalSystem accounts have this privilege.

[According to the MSDN documentation on privilege constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716.aspx), this is equivalent to the `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME`/`SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege` privilege. The Carbon PowerShell module has a [Grant-Privilege](http://get-carbon.org/help/Grant-Privilege.html) function you can use to grant this privilege from a console. (*Disclosure: I am the owner/maintainer of Carbon.*)

Comment: In case of domain accounts, there are some scenarios where adding `SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege` doesn't work. 
If I connect as local user, I can execute code under different credentials, but can't get it to work when calling `chef-client` as a domain user.